# Unable to create a chatroom using errbot commands, resulting in not_allowed_token_type error

Tags: python, slack, slack-api, errbot

When I call

```
!room create #example-room
```

in slack, i get a response:

```
Computer says nooo. See logs for details:
Slack API call to channels.create failed: not_allowed_token_type
```

The Slack API (here: https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.create) makes it sound as if bots are not allowed to call Chatroom methods , though I assume that because of the existence of the !room create command that there must be a way. 
Could someone help me with creating a chatroom in slack?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'll need to configure errbot to use a [regular Slack user account, and not a Bot account](http://errbot.io/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/slack.html):

> You will need to have an account at Slack for the bot to use, either a bot account (recommended) or a regular user account.

See if that approach works, as Bots are indeed not allowed to create channels.

Comment: Seems like that may be the only solution. If  bot accounts just limit your functionality,  why is it recommended over a regular user account? Does using a user account have other downsides I am not aware of?

Comment: Purely a guess, but I imagine you wouldn't want to share `errbot` access with anyone else if you've granted it a token to represent an actual Slack user rather than a bot. A bot account seems to be able to perform many tasks in Slack but has some interesting limitations.